# Wget not converting links and downloading properly?

Tags: wget

When running

```
wget -r -k -l 1 "http://econ.ucsb.edu/~tedb/Courses/GraduateTheoryUCSB/TheoryF16.html"`
```

the process successfully completes but a number of files are not downloaded and a number of absolute links are not converted.
For example, the file *BlumeSimonCh21.pdf* is linked twice in the html source code, one as relative and another as absolute path, both belonging to the same host. The latter links to the actual website over the internet rather than linking to the local file. Moreover, the file *Bernoulli.pdf* is not downloaded by `wget` despite being in the same host directory. I tried adding `-H` to the `wget` command, these problems still occur. Is it a bug?

Some other thoguhts: The manual says when `-r` is specified, `wget` downloads simply overwrite the old file with the new one if they are the same file. Maybe this has to do with redownloading the files?

EDIT: I am running the newest `wget` release to date, 1.18 on Arch Linux.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is resolved in the GNU wget bugs page http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?50173. It seems the issue is fixed in the new alpha version 1.19.

Comment: I have 1.19.4 and still the relative URLs are resolved wrong.